# usage of async methods for webservice

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I want to program a little Silverlight application where I have three DataGrids.
Each Datagrid gets its data from a webservice using async methods. 
Now I want the first data grid to get the data from the webservice and than get the second datagrid the data from the webservice with parameters from the selected row in the first datagrid and the third datagrid with parameters from the first two datagrids.
The first datagrid gets the data in the MainPage method via registering the event handler and than use the async method.

Now my problem is that I use the async methods for the other datagrids in the SelectionChanged (event handling) methods and I guess that the concept of this is wrong, because after selecting something in datagrid 2 and going back to datagrid 1 all datagrids dissapear.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Rebat.SymptomeService;


namespace Rebat
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
           client.SymptomeListCompleted += new EventHandler<SymptomeListCompletedEventArgs>(client_SymptomeListCompleted);
            client.SymptomeListAsync();
        }


        void client_SymptomeListCompleted(object sender, SymptomeListCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomerGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
        void client_CustomerListCompleted(object sender, CustomerListCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           CustomerGrid2.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }
        void client_SalzListCompleted(object sender, SalzListCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            SalzGrid.ItemsSource = e.Result;
        }

        private void CustomerGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Symptome sympt = CustomerGrid.SelectedItem as Symptome;
            client.CustomerListCompleted += new EventHandler<CustomerListCompletedEventArgs>(client_CustomerListCompleted);
            client.CustomerListAsync(sympt.sId.ToString());

        }

        private void CustomerGrid2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Symptome2 sympt2 = CustomerGrid2.SelectedItem as Symptome2;
            client.SalzListCompleted += new EventHandler<SalzListCompletedEventArgs>(client_SalzListCompleted);
            //this is the PROBLEM:
            client.SalzListAsync(sympt2.sy1.ToString(), sympt2.sy2.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

What do I have to change, or how do I have to use the async methods?
Can you use an async method within an event handling method? Does this apply to the usage of consuming a webservice?

Comment: Is this using WCF or ASMX? And which Silverlight and .NET versions?

Comment: It's WCF. Silverlight 5 and .Net 4.5 I guess, but does that matter?

Comment: Among other things, with .NET 4.5, you get to use the `await` keyword, which may simplify things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use the .NET 4.5 async features, doing that kind of call is a lot simpler if you adapt your serviceproxy to the Task based Async Pattern.
You can use an async method in a event handler, you will only have to make it async as well to fully benefit from the new async/await keywords.

To adapt your proxy, first declare a helper static class:

```
public static partial class TAPExtensions
{
    public static void HandleCompletion<T>(TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args, Func<T> getResult, Action unregisterHandler = null)
    {
        // Transfers the results from the AsyncCompletedEventArgs and getResult() to the 
        // TaskCompletionSource, but only AsyncCompletedEventArg's UserState matches the TCS 
        // (this check is important if the same WebClient is used for multiple, asynchronous 
        // operations concurrently).  Also unregisters the handler to avoid a leak. 
        if (args.UserState == tcs)
        {
            if (args.Cancelled) tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else if (args.Error != null) tcs.TrySetException(args.Error);
            else tcs.TrySetResult(getResult());
            if (unregisterHandler != null) unregisterHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, create another helper class to extend your proxy. Create an adapter method for each of your operations:

```
public static class ServiceClientEx
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<ReturnType>> SalzListTask(this ServiceClient proxy, string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<ReturnType>>();
        EventHandler<SalzListCompletedEventArgs> handler = (s, args) => TAPExtensions.HandleCompletion(tcs, args, () => args.Result);
        proxy.SalzListCompleted += handler;

        try
        {
            proxy.SalzListAsync(arg1, arg2, tcs);
            return await tcs.Task;
        }
        finally { proxy.SalzListCompleted -= handler; }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the extension methods in your code (assuming you add a "using" directive for the namespace of the ServiceClientEx class). The result would be something like this:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    }


    private async void CustomerGrid2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Symptome2 sympt2 = CustomerGrid2.SelectedItem as Symptome2;

        alzGrid.ItemsSource = await client.SalzListTask(sympt2.sy1.ToString(), sympt2.sy2.ToString());
    }
}
```

Note the use of the "async" keyword in the eventhandler declaration. It will propagate the async behavior to the method: once the selection changes, the handler will execute normally until it reaches the first await, when it will return to the original caller (the control's dispatcher). The continuation (setting the itemssource to the operation result) will be executed in the UIThread, when the call finishes.

You can even wrap the call to check for exceptions, like:

```
private async void CustomerGrid2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try{
            Symptome2 sympt2 = CustomerGrid2.SelectedItem as Symptome2;

            alzGrid.ItemsSource = await client.SalzListTask(sympt2.sy1.ToString(), sympt2.sy2.ToString());
        }catch(MyException ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Some suggestions:

- I do not think firing async calls from the constructor is a good idea. You could fire it after some initialization in the Loaded event of the control, for example (a better aproach would be performing this kind of operation in your ViewModel, following the MVVM pattern and just consuming it from your UI, but that is another topic).
- The way you are doing it now, an new handler will be added to your proxy every time the selection changes, so your handler will be executed more times than necessary.
- Try to instantiate your proxy every time you make a call because if the proxy faults, the instance will became unusable.